# How to generate Unicode "Immutable Identifiers" chars in Java?

Tags: java, unicode

I am trying to validate if a dependency can work with some specific unicode chars called `Immutable identifier`: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr31/#Immutable_Identifier_Syntax

The defintion of "Immutable identifier" chars is

```
Immutable Identifiers: To meet this requirement, an implementation shall define identifiers to be any non-empty string of characters that contains no character having any of the following property values:

Pattern_White_Space=True
Pattern_Syntax=True
General_Category=Private_Use, Surrogate, or Control
Noncharacter_Code_Point=True
```

I am able to figure out what's `Surrogate`, `PRIVATE_USE` and `Control` chars in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html but unable to find the rest.
This Unicode doc is also kinda complex to me so I failed to understand it and found the codepoint range for those "immutable identifier" chars :(. can anyone with some context shine some light?

Comment: As it stands your question is vague and unclear. Can you update it to clarify exactly what you need help with? Also, show us what you have done so far to identify the immutable characters. Without any code in your question it is more likely to be downvoted and/or closed.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the javadoc of [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), especially the (Unicode) classes table. But it also contains Unicode reference links.

```
"\\p{Space}"   // Whitespace
"\\p{Punct}"   // Interpunction
"\\p{M}"       // Combined diacritical marks, zero-width accents
```

And more.

Furthermore you might want to normalize the identifier. "é" can be written as one Unicode code point, or two code points: a latin `e` and a zero-width accent. `java.text.Normalizer` can do that. Compressed (one code point) seems best.

---

Please take a look at the [UAX](https://unicode.org/reports/tr31/#R3).

```
"\\p{Pattern_Syntax}"
```

Not sure but Pattern_Syntax chars probably contain `[]?+*.`, so I would think Interpunction would do too.

Comment: I checked the doc and didn't find the chars which I want to access. for example, the `Pattern_Syntax` category is not found in the table

Comment: The javadoc of `Pattern` cannot document all - it is already amazing how much Unicode knowledge resides in Java SE. So one has to dive into Unicode reference material. Or maybe you can find the Java source code of all those category names. Added to the answer Pattern_Syntax.